# C# Windows Forms How to keep control's location and size relatively constant to its parent container?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, position, size

**How I need it:**

[image: left to right]

**Dock:**

I don't want to dock it to any of sides basically.

**Anchor to all sides:**

[image: keeps the corner location constant]

**Anchor None:**

It does keeps the locations relatively constant but doesn't resize them at all.

And I am out of options apart from modifying the Resize event of the container Control and iterate through all its children I believe.

Please show me a cleaner way, thanks.

***Edit:***
I will have multiple controls floating in this container. So, `TableLayoutView` is not an option for this case.

Also, in answer from sam he suggests to manually do the job like I was afraid of. Well, I guess I will have to do it like that.

Which is manually iterating through the children controls on the `Resize` event of the container control.

I will mark this as solved although I am not satisfied.

Comment: That looks like scaling, a job of `ViewBox` in WPF, but I don't think it will be easy in winforms. Manual resizing is one possibitiliy: subscribe to container [`SizeChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and reposition children. Or try using `TableLayoutPanel` with relative units for columns and rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Result:

[Resizing done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPGb2.gif)

I have this class which holds references to the container and its children.
Foreign `DynoPanel` here holds a control inside it.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, DynoPanel> children;
public Panel container;
private List<Rectangle> startingRectangles;

public DynoContainer(Control parent)
{
    children = new Dictionary<string, DynoPanel>();
    container = new Panel
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
    parent.Controls.Add(container);
    container.FindForm().ResizeBegin += OnResizeBegin;
    container.Resize += ContainerOnResize;
}
```

Here we store the Starting locations and sizes of container and its children on the `ResizeBegin` event of the mother form:

```
private void OnResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    startingRectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
    startingRectangles.Add(container.Bounds);
    foreach (var dynoPanel in children)
        startingRectangles.Add(dynoPanel.Value.self.Bounds);
}
```

Then according to the new scale factor we calculated, children's locations and sizes are set, conserving the initial ratio on actual `Resize` event:

```
private void ContainerOnResize(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var scale = new PointF(
        (float) container.Width/startingRectangles[0].Width,
        (float) container.Height/startingRectangles[0].Height);
    int index = 1;
    foreach (var panel in children)
    {
        panel.Value.self.Location = new Point(
            (int) (startingRectangles[index].X*scale.X),
            (int) (startingRectangles[index].Y*scale.Y)
            );
        panel.Value.self.Size = new Size(
            (int) (startingRectangles[index].Width*scale.X),
            (int) (startingRectangles[index].Height*scale.Y)
            );
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AliAliyev it could be any [panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel?view=net-5.0) object. It really doesn't matter. The point is, references to the parent and children objects should be stored on OnResizeBegin() callback and modified on ContainerOnResize() callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want your inner element always distant from the left border 1% of the total window width. You can calculate your actual value after the initialization of your form.

While resizing (there's an event) recalculate the concrete left position by calculating the new distance and assigning it `Left = form.Width*0.01`